Why qbox gives meson setup fail issues when writing make in build
While building qbox on my system in facing the issues
github link for qbox: https://github.com/quic/qbox

Error :
../../../../libqemu-src/ui/meson.build:176:22: ERROR: Subproject exists but has no meson.build file.

A full log can be found at /home/kpit/Desktop/qbox/build/_deps/libqemu-build/qemu-prefix/src/qemu-build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt

ERROR: meson setup failed
make[2]: *** [_deps/libqemu-build/CMakeFiles/qemu.dir/build.make:107: _deps/libqemu-build/qemu-prefix/src/qemu-stamp/qemu-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4730: _deps/libqemu-build/CMakeFiles/qemu.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2

I was building the qbox on my system and facing errors from meson setup
